# Setting expiration TTL on MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, typeorm

How do you set ttl expiration using Typeorm with a mongoDB collection? I would like to have the records removed automatically and this is easy to do with mongoose, but I can't figure out how it's done using TypeOrm.

In mongoose it's done like this

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const YourSchema = new Schema({
 expireAt: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000   // expires in 10 minutes
 },
});
```

this is my entity code I tried, but it fails with an unknown error.

```
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, Index, IndexOptions, ObjectID, ObjectIdColumn, Repository, UpdateDateColumn, getConnection } from 'typeorm'

import uuid from 'node-uuid'

const indexOpts: IndexOptions = {
  expireAfterSeconds: 10 * 60 * 60, // expires in 10 minutes,
}

@Entity()
export class RefreshToken {
  @Index(indexOpts)
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  public id!: ObjectID

  @CreateDateColumn()
  public createdAt!: string

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  public updatedAt!: string

  @Column()
  public userId!: string

  @Column()
  public token: string = uuid.v4()
}
```

Update thanks to @Jijo_Alexander I have added the following

```
export const getRefreshTokenModelRepo = async (): Promise<MongoRepository<RefreshToken>> => {
  const repo = getMongoRepository(RefreshToken)
  const expireAfterSeconds = 600 // 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
  await repo.createCollectionIndex('refreshTokenExpireIndex', { expireAfterSeconds })
  return repo
}
```

But the records added will not auto delete. So maybe I am missing something with how indexes work in mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `createCollectionIndex`

```
getConnection.createCollectionIndex(RefreshToken, "public", { expireAfterSeconds: 600 }); //  expires in 10 minutes
```

- The indexed field must be BSON date type or an array of BSON dates
- If the indexed field in a document is not a date or an array that holds a date value(s), the document will not expire.
- If a document does not contain the indexed field, the document will not expire.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I've updated my question with new code

Comment: I'm not that much familiar with TypeORM but definitely, Mongo, so from my knowledge while creating an index with TTL to delete automatically, It should be on a timestamp field. So can you please try with lastModifiedDate, createdDate kind of fields... Adding a sample using MongoDB syntax

db.eventlog.createIndex( { "lastModifiedDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 600 } )

Comment: Typeorm doesn't seem to work with timestamp. I've tried date object on createdDate but no luck still.

Comment: there is no datetime but there is a date object. It is finally working with your help thanks. The script took longer to execute but mongoldb finally cleared the records eventually by itself.

Comment: If this answer is useful, please mark.. Thanks